# Recognise txt file characteristics

Tags: .net, vb.net

I am trying to develop a software in which the user will open a txt file filled with data.
I want to read the data but I don't know if the txt file is Delimited or Fixed Field and if is delimited what is the field delimiter (, or ; or  / etc ) or the line delimiter (CR+LF or CR or CF etc).
I know how to read a file if I know all these but can I find out these characteristics in an automatic way?
Thanks

Comment: Quite a difficult task, also Microsoft ask you (the user) to specify how you have formatted your text file when you try to import in some of its applications

Comment: If you make the file then you will know how to read ..

Comment: Perhaps counting the number of common delimiters per line, and then determine if delimiter count per line is the same for all lines *may* indicate this to a degree. However, due to the complexity of data and data types (especially when considering random files like this) you'd be better off limiting the accepted format and making sure your users know it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can read the file and make some educated guesses.

Are there CR/LFs ?

If not, it's most likely fixed length, who would specify another line delimiter.

If so, read all lines and count the number of all characters individually.

Is there a character that appears on each line the same number of times?
If so, it's likely the field delimiter. 
If not, it's probably fixed length fields.

If it's fixed length fields, build one line with statistics. For each character, what percentage of blanks over all lines and what percentage of non-blanks over all lines does it have? Find the points where indexes jump from very-high-blank-percentage to very-low-blank-percentage, that is likely to be a field boundary (the last field ending in blanks because it's not "full", the next starting with a non-blank because it's filled.)

Comment: I'll try it and let you know

Answer (score 1):

You can make a good guess: look at [file](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?file) for inspiration.

For example:

1. read a chunk of data (pick some size that's big enough it should contain a whole line)
2. scan it for CR, LF, likely delimiter characters and whitespace
3. did it have CR+LF? were they always together?
4. did you find any delimiters? If you found more than one, can you see any pattern?
5. did you find runs of whitespace always ending at the same column on successive lines?

etc. etc.

Comment: I'll try it and let you know